# Angular / Jasmine / Karma - can't start app due to $http call in main module

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I manually bootstrap my Angular app following the response to an API call (and corresponding setting of a constant), thus:

```
(function() {

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

    // Bootstrap the app once we've got a config
    var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
    var $http = initInjector.get('$http');

    $http.get('/api/configs').then(
        function(response) {
            myApp.constant('myConfig', response.data);
            bootstrapApp();
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log('Unable to get config', error);
        }
    );

    function bootstrapApp() {
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
        });
    }

})();
```

This is preventing my tests from running as the `$http` call isn't being mocked.

```
04 07 2017 14:05:53.965:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
04 07 2017 14:05:53.987:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
04 07 2017 14:05:55.169:INFO [Chrome 59.0.3071 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#y-gZChEZ25VdBB7YAAAA with id manual-6637
04 07 2017 14:05:56.270:WARN [web-server]: 404: /api/configs
```

As you can see, the `/api/configs` call is unsurprisingly 404'ing.

I can't get my head around how to mock this. Creating a test for this module and mocking the `$http` call doesn't fix it as the call is being made when Karma starts the app.

It feels like I need a "global" `$http` mock that is available to the test runner when it starts. But I could barking up completely the wrong tree.

Does anyone have any thoughts? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to have a setup file that is added in the `files:[ 'mysetup.js', ... ]` in `karma.conf.js`. There you can mock the $http something like this:

```
//----mysetup.js----
var response = null;
var replaceHttpGet = function( get ){
    get.success( response ); // or whatever you need
};
//another variable for failure
```

and then you can do in your test:

```
//---in test---
var oldHttpGet = $http.get;
$http.get = replaceHttpGet;
response = { //mock response };
...test...
$http.get=oldHttpGet;
```